# How to make an Image fit into an ImageButton using onActivityResult method

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult, android-imagebutton

I want to set any image from my phone gallery **fit** the imageButton , and also without it being **rotated**. When i try to access the image from my gallery it doesnt fit well and my imageButton comes while it's rotated. How can i get rid of this.

Below is `java` code

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imageSelect;
    private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private EditText mPostTitle;
    private EditText mPostDesc;
    private Button postButton;
    private  Uri imageUri = null;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post_activity);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
 /*        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Post a Picture");*/
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        imageSelect = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
        mPostTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mPostTitle);
        mPostDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mPostDesc);
        postButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);
        imageSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });


        postButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startPosting();
            }
        });


    }

    private void startPosting() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
        mProgress.show();

        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) &&!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && imageUri!=null){

      StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("BlogImages").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
      filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


              Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
              DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
              newPost.child("title").setValue(title_val);
              newPost.child("description").setValue(desc_val);
              newPost.child("imageUrl").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
            //  newPost.child("uid").setValue(FirebaseAuth.getc);


              mProgress.dismiss();

              startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
          }
      });


  }



    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


             imageUri = data.getData();
            imageSelect.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }


}
```

so my `onActivityResult` result is also included above.

Below is my `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageSelect"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@mipmap/add_btn"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <include layout="@layout/content_post" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: take a look at picasso, its a java library for android which helps with images, you kinda have to get used to it but its great for loading in images based on whatever your code does.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the image to fill the bounds of the `ImageButton`. You could do this with the attribute [`android:adjustViewBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds).

If you want to disable screen roatation, set the `android:screenOrientation` to portrait or landscape in the `activity` element in your `Manifest.xml`.

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered your question that solve the rotation issue as well you can try that for this problem also.

[Compression and rotation of image picked from gallery is solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373093/compressing-an-image-before-uploading-it-to-firebase-storage/40374731#40374731)