# Compressing an Image before Uploading it to Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, image-compression

I am trying to Compress an Image before Uploading it to `Firebase Storage` using `SiliCompressor` library , but it seems  not working , the `ProgressDialog` doesn't stop.  What i first did was to pick the Image from the Gallery  into an ImageButton  by clicking an ImageButton. Below is my code.

```
imageSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

---------------------------------------------------------------------

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            imageUri = data.getData();

           // imageSelect.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageSelectFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        //    Compressor com = Compressor.getDefault(this).compressToFile(imageFile);
           // imageSelect.setImageURI(imageUri);
            Picasso.with(c).load(imageUri).fit().into(imageSelect);

        }
    }
```

So now am having a Method `startPosting()` which Uploads data By a click of  Button to Firebase Storage.
Below is my code.

```
 private void startPosting() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
        //Compressing an Image ....
        String stringUri= imageUri.toString();
        Uri uri_image_final;
        //String filePath = SiliCompressor.with(getApplicationContext()).compress(stringUri);
        String filePath = SiliCompressor.with(getApplicationContext()).compress(stringUri, true);
        uri_image_final = Uri.parse(filePath);
        System.out.println("Whats here :" +
                ""+ uri_image_final);

        final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && filePath != null) {
            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("BlogImages").child(uri_image_final.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri_image_final).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    DatabaseReference c = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("EventTitle").setValue(title_val);
                    newPost.child("EventDescription").setValue(desc_val);
                    newPost.child("EventImage").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                    newPost.child("PostId").setValue(c);



                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));


                }
            }


            );


        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && imageUri != null) {
            mProgress.show();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("BlogImages").child(uri_image_final.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri_image_final).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                    Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                    newPost.child("EventTitle").setValue("");
                    newPost.child("EventDescription").setValue("");
                    newPost.child("EventImage").setValue(downloadUri.toString());


                    mProgress.dismiss();
                   // startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                  Intent load=  new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    load.putExtra(eventname,eventname);
                    startActivity(load);


                }
            }


            );

        }

        else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && imageUri== null){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please insert an Image and Upload ! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
```

Now if you see in that Method , my essence was to Compress an Image which is loaded in the ImageButton, then Afterwards it Uploads to firebase.
This is the line of `Silicon Compressor` which tries to compress an image loaded in the ImageButton.

```
 String filePath = SiliCompressor.with(getApplicationContext()).compress(stringUri, true);
```

I got this lib from this link of Github.
https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor

So where am i wrong please because the Image is not Uploading but i want it to Upload while it's compressed.

Comment: One tool to consider is the official Firebase "resize images" extension - https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images - though it's unclear how compressed the resized image is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I have written, you can try it.

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.PICK_USER_PROFILE_IMAGE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bitmap bmp = ImagePicker.getImageFromResult(this, resultCode, data);//your compressed bitmap here
                startPosting(bmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your startPosting method should be like this

```
 private void startPosting(Bitmap bmp) {
    byte[] data = bmp.toByteArray();
    mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Image...");

    final String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    final String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && filePath != null) {
        mProgress.show();
        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("BlogImages").child(uri_image_final.getLastPathSegment());


        UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
              }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
            DatabaseReference c = mDatabase.push();
            newPost.child("EventTitle").setValue(title_val);
            newPost.child("EventDescription").setValue(desc_val);
            newPost.child("EventImage").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
            newPost.child("PostId").setValue(c);



            mProgress.dismiss();
            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));


        }
    });


    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && imageUri != null) {
        mProgress.show();
        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("BlogImages").child(uri_image_final.getLastPathSegment());
        UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
              }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
                newPost.child("EventTitle").setValue("");
                newPost.child("EventDescription").setValue("");
                newPost.child("EventImage").setValue(downloadUri.toString());


                mProgress.dismiss();
               // startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                Intent load=  new Intent(PostActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                load.putExtra(eventname,eventname);
                startActivity(load);


            }
        });

    }

    else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val) && imageUri== null){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please insert an Image and Upload ! ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Below is the class ImagePicker that have series of methods to do your work

```
public class ImagePicker {

private static final int DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY = 400;        // min pixels
private static final String TAG = "ImagePicker";
private static final String TEMP_IMAGE_NAME = "tempImage";

public static int minWidthQuality = DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH_QUALITY;

public static Bitmap getImageFromResult(Context context, int resultCode,
                                        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getImageFromResult, resultCode: " + resultCode);
    Bitmap bm = null;
    File imageFile = getTempFile(context);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage;
        boolean isCamera = (imageReturnedIntent == null ||
                imageReturnedIntent.getData() == null ||
                imageReturnedIntent.getData().equals(Uri.fromFile(imageFile)));
        if (isCamera) {     /** CAMERA **/
            selectedImage = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        } else {            /** ALBUM **/
            selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "selectedImage: " + selectedImage);

        bm = getImageResized(context, selectedImage);
        int rotation = getRotation(context, selectedImage, isCamera);
        bm = rotate(bm, rotation);
    }
    return bm;
}


private static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Context context, Uri theUri, int sampleSize) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;

    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        fileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(theUri, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap actuallyUsableBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(
            fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);

    Log.d(TAG, options.inSampleSize + " sample method bitmap ... " +
            actuallyUsableBitmap.getWidth() + " " + actuallyUsableBitmap.getHeight());

    return actuallyUsableBitmap;
}

/**
 * Resize to avoid using too much memory loading big images (e.g.: 2560*1920)
 **/
private static Bitmap getImageResized(Context context, Uri selectedImage) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    int[] sampleSizes = new int[]{5, 3, 2, 1};
    int i = 0;
    do {
        bm = decodeBitmap(context, selectedImage, sampleSizes[i]);
        Log.d(TAG, "resizer: new bitmap width = " + bm.getWidth());
        i++;
    } while (bm.getWidth() < minWidthQuality && i < sampleSizes.length);
    return bm;
}


private static int getRotation(Context context, Uri imageUri, boolean isCamera) {
    int rotation;
    if (isCamera) {
        rotation = getRotationFromCamera(context, imageUri);
    } else {
        rotation = getRotationFromGallery(context, imageUri);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Image rotation: " + rotation);
    return rotation;
}

private static int getRotationFromCamera(Context context, Uri imageFile) {
    int rotate = 0;
    try {

        context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageFile, null);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imageFile.getPath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotate = 270;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotate = 180;
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotate = 90;
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rotate;
}

public static int getRotationFromGallery(Context context, Uri imageUri) {
    String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(imageUri, columns, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) return 0;

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int orientationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(columns[0]);
    return cursor.getInt(orientationColumnIndex);
}


private static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bm, int rotation) {
    if (rotation != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        return bmOut;
    }
    return bm;
}


 private static File getTempFile(Context context) {
        File imageFile = new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), TEMP_IMAGE_NAME);
        imageFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        return imageFile;
    }
}
```

The ImagePicker Class have all the methods of handling compression as well as rotation of image.

Hope it will help

Thanks to this link for uploading file ref

[Uploading files on firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files)

Comment: Thanks @rana , i am trying to implement `ImagePicker` class but `getTempFile()` is missing.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifah getTempFile is added :)

Comment: thanks but am  still confused , `onActivityResult()` , is where am seeing your are Uploading  the image plus the compression , your track is right but please can you try to show how i can put it in my  ` startPosting()`  Method , and what exactly i have to put in `onActivityResult()` ., because am still a beginner.

Comment: You can post bitmap that I get in onActivityResult and post it to firebase as it is than post its url to firebase node. your startPosting method have your checks your can simple implement on my code. :)

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifah I changed your starposting() method kindly have a look but their might be some error in the code because I just write the code on my assumption and didnt actually build the code.

Comment: Thanks so much  @rana

Answer (score 2):

I have done this way:

```
private void startPosting() {

        mProgress.setMessage(getString(R.string.downloading_route));

        final String titleVal  = mRouteTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String descVal  = mRouteDesc.getText().toString().trim();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleVal) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(descVal) && mImageUri != null) {

            mProgress.show();

            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Route images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

            //compress image
            mSelectImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mSelectImage.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bitmap = mSelectImage.getDrawingCache();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putBytes(data);

            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                    final Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();

                    mDatabaseUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            newPost.child("title").setValue(titleVal);
                            newPost.child("desc").setValue(descVal);
                            newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                            newPost.child("uid").setValue(mCurrentUser.getUid());
                            newPost.child("username").setValue(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    startActivity(new Intent(AddRouteActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                                }
                            });

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {



                        }
                    });

                    mProgress.dismiss();

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> //declear local variable first

Bitmap bitmap;
Uri imageUri;

> //button action to call Image picker method

```
ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Pick Image"),GALLERY_REQ_CODE);
        }
    });
```

> //get bitmap from onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
}
```

> //compress image first then upload to firebase

```
public void postImage() {
    StorageReference storageReference = mStorageRef.child("Images/" + //imageName);
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobs").child(//imageName);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(SaveJobActivity.this.getContentResolver(),bitmap,//imageName,null);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
    storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Map<String, Object> update_hashMap = new HashMap<>();

            **//assign download url in hashmap to upadate database reference**

                        update_hashMap.put("Image",downloadUrl);

            **//update database children here**

                        databaseReference.updateChildren(update_hashMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                    //do what you want
                                }else {
                                    //show exception
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        //show exception
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```